# C++ Object Construction inside a Class

Tags: c++, class, object

I have three classes; their function definitions are in a sperate file.
I'm trying to construct an object with various parameters inside another class without using inline implementation.

```
class A{     
     public:
       A(){}  
};

class B{         
     public:
         //takes in two ints, one reference to object, and a string 
         B(int x, int y, A &a, std::string s );
};

class C{        
    public:            
        //in the constructor, construct b_obj with its parameters 
        C();

    private:
        B b_obj;
 };
```

How can I make the `C` constructor construct `b_obj` with its parameters of the int, the reference to an instance of `A`, and the string? I tried some methods but I get an error that complains about no match call to the `b_obj` constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the relevant items to a constructor of object C, and then use an initializer.

```
class C {
    public:
        C(int x, int y, A& a, std::string s) : b_obj(x, y, a, s) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an initializer:

```
C() : b_obj(5, 6, A(), ""){}
```

This line technically won't work, though, because B's constructor takes an `A&`, so you can't bind a temporary to it. `const A &` if it's not being changed, or `A` if it is, would work out better if you don't have a non-temporary `A` to pass in.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, I was just getting to that :)